# Saving changed Activity background colour on button click

Tags: java, android, view, save, background-color

I have this code which allows me to change the background colour of my activity and I call this on a button click.

```
View someView = findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
View root = someView.getRootView();
root.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);
```

How can I save the background colour so that it stays changed whenever the app is restarted.

Comment: Use sharedPreferences to save and retrieve the value next time when application is started. @user1353517

Comment: @Pooja Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to persist this setting across multiple starts by the user use `SharedPreferences` as described here:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

If you only want to keep this setting when re-created by the system because of orientation changes for example, use `onSaveInstanceState()` and check for a `Bundle` in `onCreate()` as described here:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Answer (score 0):

Save to SharedPref.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(KEY, Value);
editor.commit();
```

Read from SharedPref.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int i = sharedPref.getInt(KEY, defaultValue);
```

Answer (score -1):

Set Flag in sharedPreferences by

```
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString(Flag, "Y");
```

And while loading the screen in Oncreate check for the flag by

```
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

  if (sharedpreferences.contains(Flag))
  {
     name.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Flag, ""));

  }
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm still confused on how to use my code with this

Comment: Declare the variable public static final String Flag = "flag";

Comment: You can put it before or after by putting editor you are just saving it.

Comment: "SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;" add this in the declaration

Comment: thanks that fixed that. However it still shows cannot resolve symbol on name.setText and MyPREFERENCES

Comment: just change "name by flag"

Comment: could you edit your example to show me how I would use this? I'm lost, I don't know what you mean by "name by flag"